# If Statements not working correctly with Javascript Radio Button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a question regarding a problem I've having with my Javascript coding.

The code is as follows:

```js
function PizzaSize(form) {

  if (form.size.value = "medium") {
    alert("A medium size pizza has been selected.")
  }

  if (form.size.value = "large") {
    alert("A large size pizza has been selected.")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="pizzaorder">
  <b><u>Size Selection</b>
  </u>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" onclick="PizzaSize(this.form)">Medium
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" onclick="PizzaSize(this.form)">Large
  <br>
</form>
```

So, when one of these radio buttons is clicked I direct it to run the following function:

However, when I test the code in a browser, it doesn't work right. When I click the "Medium" radio button, I get a message stating "A medium size pizza has been selected." When I click OK on the message, the radio button value then changes so it selects a large size pizza instead, and then I get a message saying "A large size pizza has been selected."

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I'd like to keep the function, but hopefully modify it so that it works correctly instead of how it's working as of now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to also put semi-colons at the end of statements, such as: `alert("A medium size pizza has been selected.");`

Comment: A single equals (`=`) is an assignment, a double equals (`==`) is a comparison. You're using the wrong ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `assignment operator =` to check equality which is wrong.

use `equality operator ==` to compare e.g.

```
if (form.size.value = "large")
{
alert ("A large size pizza has been selected.")
}
```

should be

```
if (form.size.value == "large")
{
alert ("A large size pizza has been selected.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! That fixed my problem and now everything is working as should! I can't choose this as the best answer for another 9 minutes, but when I can, it will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

There a 3 operators: "=", "==", and "===".  Use the == operator to check if things are similar.  The "=" operator SETS the right expression to the left expression.

```js
function PizzaSize(form) {

  if (form.size.value == "medium") {
    alert("A medium size pizza has been selected.")
  }

  if (form.size.value == "large") {
    alert("A large size pizza has been selected.")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="pizzaorder">
  <b><u>Size Selection</b>
  </u>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" onclick="PizzaSize(this.form)">Medium
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" onclick="PizzaSize(this.form)">Large
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: It is better to use the === because it also checks the types. I.E> '1'==1 returns true while '1'===1 return false.

Comment: Yes, I know, @Eyal.  I recommend == for beginners so they don't get confused.  Because == always works, === only works for equals.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a comparison operator (==) and so your conditions are returning true.

The better way to do this is to listen for change on the input and then run your logic.

As written, you can parse **this** in the PizzaSize function instead of **this.form**

Then..

```
function PizzaSize(radioInput) {

   if (radioInput.value=="medium") {
       //do stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with Firefox, the code needs to be written like this:

```
if (form.elements.size[0].checked)
{
    alert("A medium size pizza has been selected.")
}

if (form.elements.size[1].checked)
{
    alert("A large size pizza has been selected.")
}
```

Note it uses `form.elements.size`, not `form.size`. That's an array, where every element corresponds to one of the radio buttons. The checked property is a boolean that tells if that radio is checked.